# How can I use the Windows SDK with Qt Creator

Tags: windows, qt

I have been trying to use the Windows SDK v7.1 in Qt Creator without much luck. Specifically, how can I set up Qt Creator so that it will compile the SDK samples in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples`?

Comment: If you're trying to use Windows-specific code in Qt, you're almost always doing it wrong (in all but the cases where Qt does not provide a mechanism for what you want to do).

Comment: Really? I was going to use it because it seems very nice for c++ UI development. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows

Comment: I think San Jacinto misunderstood your intention and you misunderstood his comment :) If you want to use Qt Creator to write UI for some Win32 API code (like examples in Windows SDK) you sure can do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create new project in Qt Creator using *File|New File or Project*, choose *Other Project* from *Projects* list and then choose *Import Existing Project* anc click *Choose...* button. Then select the folder with SDK example, click *Next* and click *Finish*. Click *Projects* on the left (or press Ctrl+5), and in *Tool chain* combo choose *Microsoft Visual C++*. Now click *Details* under *Build Environment*, check *Clear system environment* and variables and their values as below:

```
COMSPEC   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
INCLUDE   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include;
LIB       C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib;
PATH      C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE x86
```

You should modify above values according to your setup (places where you installed Visual C++ and where you installed Windows SDK).

Now click *Build All* (or press Ctrl+Shift+B) and the example should be built.