# How to register a service using C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, service

I have a Qt/C++ application. The application needs to register an npapi browser plugin which is registered using the following command:

```
regsvr32 npmyplugin.dll
```

I can use QProcess or even system() function, but to register a service administrative privileges are required. How can I start the service in this case.

Comment: And can you provide that privileges?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Actually a sort of runas administrator is required, where a user is prompted like in UAC

Comment: You need to use `ShellExecuteEx` to run process with elevated priviledges - take a look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893262/how-can-i-run-a-child-process-that-requires-elevation-and-wait

Comment: @NemanjaBoric How do I use it in Qt application

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Qt Creator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to elevate your privileges once you start the process. However, you can require for higher privileges when starting a new process. As you're on Windows, just use `ShellExecuteEx` and set `runas` in `lpVerb` field of `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`:

```
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExInfo = {0};
    shExInfo.cbSize = sizeof(shExInfo);
    shExInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    shExInfo.hwnd = 0;
    shExInfo.lpVerb = _T("runas");                 // Operation to perform
    shExInfo.lpFile = _T("regsvr32.exe");          // Application to start    
    shExInfo.lpParameters = _T("npmyplugin.dll");  // Additional parameters
    shExInfo.lpDirectory = 0;
    shExInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    shExInfo.hInstApp = 0;  

    ShellExecuteEx(&shExInfo);
    return 0;
```

To use this in a Qt application, just `#include <windows.h>` and make sure include and lib variables are set properly for the Windows SDK.

For setting up Qt creator with Windows SDK, check this question: [How can I use the Windows SDK with Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791808/how-can-i-use-the-windows-sdk-with-qt-creator)

The original code is comming from the accepted answer in this question:
[How can I run a child process that requires elevation and wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893262/how-can-i-run-a-child-process-that-requires-elevation-and-wait)

Comment: I am getting following error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286513/lnk-2019-shellexecuteex-unresolved-external-symbol-qt-creator

Comment: You need to setup Qt Creator to work with Windows SDK (see the link in my answer) and you need to link your program against Shell32.lib.